# How to narrow testing examples in `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to load mnist data using

```
test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./mnist_data/', train=False, transform=transforms.ToTensor(), download=False)

test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=test_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False)
```

However this code will load all 10000 test examples of hand written datapoints. Is there any opportunity to have test_loader exactly in the same type and to narrow its loading only to 100?

I tried intuitively to do:

```
test_loader.dataset = test_loader.dataset[0:99]
```

But I obtained error:

```
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

Because python doesn't understand object `test_loader.dataset[0:99]`.

Could you please help me solving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may approach to this a bit differently. For example use a loop to iterate 100 times and in each iteration you can get a sample from a dataset. It may look like this:

```py
test_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./mnist_data/', train=False, transform=transforms.ToTensor(), download=False)

# make it iterative object

test_dataset_iter = iter(test_dataset)

# then you can get a sample by `next` function

for _ in range(100):
   image, label = next(test_dataset_iter)
```